# Javascript ignoring all files as opposed to one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my javascript to ignore one file type extension that's held in a folder with a bunch of photoshop images. For all of the other file types in the folder I have it so that these file types populate a window and the user can import into their work space.

I have modified my script to ignore the file extension I want ignored, however it no longer populates the window with all of the other file types containted in the folder. But when I take out the file I want ignore from the folder, the window gets populated as it should.

This is what I have at the moment that checks my folder for the file types:

```
//Prompt for folder location
var Path = Folder.selectDialog("Select Folder Location for Renders")
// Use the path to the application and append the samples folder 
var samplesFolder = Folder(Path)
//Get the files 
var fileList = samplesFolder.getFiles()
//Creat Array to hold names
var renderTypes = new Array();
//Parse Initial name to get similar render elements
var beautyRender = fileList[0].name
beautyRender = beautyRender.substr(0, beautyRender.length-4)


//Get the render elements with a similar name
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
  var filename = fileList[i].name;
   if (filename.match(/\.(stitchinfo)$/i) == null) 
   {
      if(fileList[i].name.substring(0,beautyRender.length) === beautyRender)
      {
        renderTypes.push(fileList[i].name); 
      }
   }
 }
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong and need to modify?

*Update* 
I'm still trying to get this to work and following the help from one of the posters below I have modified my code to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
  var filename = fileList[i].name;
   if (filename.match(/\.(stitchinfo)$/i) == null) 
   {
        renderTypes.push(fileList[i].name); 
   }
}
```

However, with this new code comes a new problem in that it returns every file contained in the folders and displays it.

I'm still stumped as to how I can get this to work as I would like. Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get a fix for this.

What I've ended up doing is creating a new function and passing that into my call for checking the folder locations.

```
function ignoreMe(f)
{
    return f.name.match(/\.(stitchinfo)$/i) == null;
}
```

And the folder check:

```
var fileList = samplesFolder.getFiles(ignoreMe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a sparse array, because you skip elements in `renderTypes` when you ignore a filename in `fileList`. That may be confusing your rendering code. Change to:

```
renderTypes.push(fileList[i].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

What if :

```
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
   var filename = fileList[i].name;
   if (filename.match(/\.(stitchinfo)$/i) == null) 
   {
      if(fileList[i].name.substring(0,beautyRender.length) === beautyRender)
      {
        renderTypes.push(fileList[i].name); 
      }
   }

}
```

1. Wrong usage of the array
2. Missing ";"
3. Unnecessary use of "continue".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I tried this and it only brings up the file it is suppose to skip over.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to invert the condition. My bad!

Comment: Again, thank you for the edit but now it brings up nothing. The window is empty and there are files in the folder for me to test with.

Comment: I don't have your data, so I cannot try it for real. Can you set up a Jsfiddle, so we can fix it?

Comment: Sorry I can't do that. It's a script for photoshop.

Comment: I made this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dw5mN/1/ It works to me. If you have some different data, please specify.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read through it. I've also updated my code to show all my member variables as well.

Comment: Hmm I commented out the second if statement in my code and this time it brings up ever single file held in the folder. Not just the first instance.